# Google Maps bicycling route

Tags: google-maps, maps

I'm using the following link to open directions from one point to another on Google Maps:

https://www.google.com/maps/?saddr=[one-point]&daddr=[another]

I would like to open the bicycling directly. Which link should I use or which parameter should I add? Adding **&mode=bicycling** does not seem to work.

Comment: Can' t you open it just by copy pasting and then specifying the start and end point? URL: https://www.google.com/maps/dir///@46.0550415,14.8135137,11z/data=!4m2!4m1!3e1?hl=en

Comment: I could do that, but what if the dudes at Google decide to change the link structure? I'd have a problem.

Comment: Well my only suggestion is to try it for a week and if it sticks you are good to go. I haven't been able to found anything in the google docs which could solve your problem entirely

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this has changed since you first asked, but I just followed your link, clicked the Cycling Icon, and then copied [the resulting URL](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Onepoint+Technologies,+3380+Trickum+Road+%23300,+Woodstock,+GA+30188/Another+Dimension+Comics,+424+10+Street+Northwest,+Calgary,+AB+T2N+1V9,+Canada/@42.2195143,-108.2656288,5z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x88f56c51891248e7:0x552f71f4717e9dc3!2m2!1d-84.484945!2d34.0836373!1m5!1m1!1s0x53716fec314f9f69:0x758fd2619c83fa76!2m2!1d-114.0856815!2d51.0565832!3e1), which seems to do what you're after.

Comparing the two URLs, the only difference I see is the addition of `!3e1` on the end of a standard "directions" URL.